# How to display form data results onto another page with node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, forms

I have to deal with bad handwriting from clients at my current job who provide their contact info on a paper form. My company is not willing to digitalize this process so I want to create a simple form with bootstrap 5 that I can have clients fill out and display their contact info, legibly, upon submission. I'm just stuck on how I can show the results or inject in a stylized html page and not do res.write(""), res.send(" ") the whole result page. Am I going the wrong way with this?

```html
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));





app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/")
});



app.post("/newsignup", function(req,res){
  
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/newsignup.html")

});

app.post("/submission", function(req,res){
  
  const name = req.body.inputName;
  const birthday = req.body.inputbirthdayMonth;
  const email = req.body.inputEmail;
  const address = req.body.inputAdress;
  const address2 = req.body.inputAddress2;
  const zip = req.body.input;
  
  console.log(name, email);

  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/result.html")
});

 




app.listen(3000, function(){ 
  console.log("Server is Running on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<form action="/submission" method="post">
    <img class="mb-4" src="images/Logo.png" alt=""width="300" height="200">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please Fill In</h1>

    <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="First and Last name" required autofocus>


    <input type="text" name="inputText" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Birthday Month" required>


    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Email Address" required>


    <input type="text" name="inputAddress" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Shipping Address">


    <input type="text" name="inputAddress2" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Apt or Suite">


    <input type="text" name="inputZip" class="form-control middle" placeholder="Zip Code" required>

    <input type="text" name="inputText" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="State" required>

    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary my-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```